# SIGSEGV segmentation fault at strftime_l lib64/libc.so.6

Tags: linux, unix

I'am porting pro*c codes from UNIX to LINUX.  The codes are compiled and created executables successfully.  But during run time its raising segmentation fault.  I debugged the code step by step and the below is the output of GDB debug.

```
 Breakpoint 4 at 0x3b19690f50
 (gdb) n
 525             strftime (buf, MAX_STRING_LEN, "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", dummy_time);
 (gdb) n

 Breakpoint 4, 0x0000003b19690f50 in strftime () from /lib64/libc.so.6
 (gdb) n
 Single stepping until exit from function strftime,
 which has no line number information.
 0x0000003b19690f70 in strftime_l () from /lib64/libc.so.6
 (gdb) n
 Single stepping until exit from function strftime_l,
 which has no line number information.

 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 0x0000003b19690f8b in strftime_l () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Actually in code the function `strftime()` is called. But I have no idea why it is reaching `strftime_l()` in /lib64/libc.so.6.

This issue is not coming in UNIX.  please help on this. code is

```
static void speed_hack_libs(void)
{
    time_t dummy_time_t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *dummy_time = localtime (&dummy_time_t);
    struct tm *other_dummy_time = gmtime (&dummy_time_t);
    char buf[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    strftime (buf, MAX_STRING_LEN, "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S", dummy_time);
}
```

Comment: please add the code to your question by editing it.

Comment: Better update the title! Nevermind Linux is a Unix(-like system)...

Comment: What's the value of MAX_STRING_LEN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
struct tm *dummy_time = localtime (&dummy_time_t);
struct tm *other_dummy_time = gmtime (&dummy_time_t);
```

This is not gonna work. From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime):

> The `localtime()` function converts the calendar time timep to broken-down time representation, expressed relative to the user's specified time-zone.  ...  **The return value points to a statically allocated struct** which might be overwritten by
>          subsequent  calls  to  any  of  the date and time functions.
>
> The `gmtime()` function converts the calendar time timep to broken-down time representation, expressed in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).   **It
>          may return NULL** when the year does not fit into an integer.  **The return value points to a statically allocated struct** which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions.

So, `*dummy_time` will probably be overwritten by the time you use it, and contain unpredictable garbage. You should copy the data to your buffer like this:

```
struct tm dummy_time ;
memcpy(&dummy_time, localtime (&dummy_time_t), sizeof(struct tm));
```

Although I'm not sure how could this cause a SIGSEGV (might be something with getting the month names etc. - check if the problem persists with `LC_ALL=C`), you must fix this before you can move on. Also, check (in the debugger) the contents of `*dummy_time`.

Comment: thanks a lot jpalecek!!! I modified code as you mentioned.  There is no segmentation fault now!!! Thanks a lot!!!! also I set environment variable LC_ALL = C and memset().  need to check if it works without LC_ALL = C and memset().

Answer (score 1):

It is calling strftime_l because you compiled 64 bit - that is the 64 bit library entry point for strftime. You have two pointers in strftime - a string and a struct tm pointer.  One of them is pointing to invalid memory.  jpalacek gave you where to look first.

Comment: sorr Jim I din't understand your point                              It is calling strftime_l because you compiled 64 bit - that is the 64 bit library entry point for strftime

Comment: You asked the implied question - how did I link to strftime_l?  The answer is that is the symbol name for the function in the libc 64 library.  Nothing is wrong.

Comment: In `strftime_l`, the trailing `_l` stands for "locale", not for "long". One function calls the other after determining the process's locale. Bare `strftime` does very little in this particular environment.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz +1.  Thanks for the correction.  My system does not have that entry point.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird... my system doesn't have a manual page for `strftime_l` but it does have a `#define` for it in `/usr/local/time.h`. I haven't actually tried to link against it, but I would fully expect that it does in fact exist for me. A reference for the `strftime_l` man page online: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html

Comment: My systems are Solaris 10 & Solaris 11.  monetary.h exists, which is a modern POSIX thing, but strftime_l exists nowhere in any of the library files or headers. A system either is or is not POSIX-compliant, the middle ground, mostly POSIX-compliant, does not grant you any points.

Answer (score -1):

Did you add the time.h header file? I think you have missed it.